# Array item as type?

Tags: typescript

Is something like this possible?
It works for objects, but what about arrays?

```
const myArray = ["foo", "bar"]

function pick(what: keyof myArray) { // keyof is obviously wrong
}

pick("foo") // okay
pick("inexistent") // error, "inexistent" does not exist in myArray
```

Comment: I think you want `(typeof myArray)[number]`, but right now that would just be `string`. `myArray` would have to be more narrowly typed to get `"foo" | "bar"` out of it.

Comment: see also https://steveholgado.com/typescript-types-from-arrays/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `as const`. It did the trick.